# How to highlight duplicates if any 3 cells match out of a range

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJQjk.png)I have a list of certain items. And I want to make combinations of the items manually.

And what I want to do is, If ****any 3 cell matches** of a row** with the previous entries, then those cells should be highlighted.

For example, I have Column A B C D and E.
In row4, I have items- Nickel,  Potassium, Gold, Calcium,   Magnesium.
Now If I add Potassium, Calcium, Magnesium to the next rows then all the matching items should be highlighted.

Any help will be appreciated.

[Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bwhC.png)

[image]

Comment: Hello Ratan, I've read your question description a couple of times but I still find it a bit confusing. Any chance you could explain it again please?

Comment: Looking at your data, rows 3 and 5 have three matching elements.  (Gold, Cobalt and Sodium).  Should these be highlighted? And if so, should they be red, the same as the other highlights?

Comment: And to clarify:  do you want to highlight only when there are exactly 3 matches, or 3 or more matches?

Answer (score -1):

Use conditional formatting, *Format cells where this formula is true*.

```
=Countif($A2:$D2,A3)
```

I applied this format to cell A3 and copied the format to other cells using the format painter. However, there are several other ways of achieving the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already tried that method but unfortunately, it's not working as expected.

Comment: I tried it too, and I can assure you it works. Therefore we have two choices. One, you don't know how to make it work for you. Two, I don't understand your expectations. Your comment doesn't help in either case..